# good voice syntheses for linux

Tags: linux, text-to-speech

is there any nice free voice syntheses software with a quality close to this At&t project http://www.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php  for linux beside espeak and gnuspeech (which i find unusable because of the bad quality of the result speech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used http://www.yakitome.com and it is really coll, and it does host your mp3 generated files, and somehow it uses the At&t speech syntheses system

Answer (score 1):

There is [festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/), but I can't speak to its sound quality.  It's a `yum install festival` away on Fedora.